# Using object to embed a pdf

Tags: php, html, pdf

I am using PHP for my website and I am using this code to display PDF files. However it does NOT display the PDF.

What is wrong or am I missing something?

PHP code:

```
echo "<object width=\"600\" height=\"800\" data=\"PDF\$row[PDF]\"
type=\"application/pdf\">"; echo "<embed src=\"PDF\$row[PDF]\" 
type=\"application/pdf\" />your browser does not support pdf"; 
echo "</object>";
```

Please help.

Comment: This is the code in PHP: echo "<object width=\"400\" height=\"400\" data=\"PDF\$row[PDF]\" type=\"application/pdf\">";
    echo "<embed src=\"PDF\$row[PDF]\" type=\"application/pdf\" />your browser does not support pdf";
   echo "</object>";

Comment: Have you used <?php and ?> tags in your php file?
Edit:
Also src=\"PDF\$row[PDF]\" must be => src=\"PDF\\$row[PDF]\"
And I am not sure what is "PDF" defined string?

Comment: you should use some think like this `echo "<input type='text' />";`

Comment: Hi SoftGuide, Yes is do use the standard php tags. I have changed the single slash to a double slash but still not working. I only get a blank page. The $row[PDF] is the string (filename including path) as extracted from mysql.